# How do I override the default page.tpl.php?

Tags: 7, theming

I have one page in my `D7` website with significant deviation from the rest of my pages. In this page I will only display a limited number of regions and in a different layout.

What is the best way to override the default `page.tpl.php`? Can I create something like "`mycustom-page.tpl.php`" that gets called ONLY on a specific url within my site?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depending for what exact content you want to make a special template there are diffrent solutions for that. Look at [Drupal 7 Template Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656). Example for a single node: `page--node--1.tpl.php`.

In case the core template suggestions do not offer the flexibility you need, you can add more suggestions based on your own criteria. This is done in a preprocess function in your theme's template.php. For more information, see [Working with template suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/223440#custom-suggestions).

Comment: absolutely perfect and amazingly simple. thumbs up to Drupal and the drupalites :)

Comment: Good answer. I added some info about adding your own template suggestions, in case @Charlie or anyone else needs it.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer will help you find the name too